# SonarQube 5.2 Widget Issue Filter on dashboard

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.2

Playing with widget, I try the Issue Filter.

Configuration is Unresolved Issues
Distribution Axis : By Project

[image]

And here is the result
[image]

Not really user friendly isn't it ?
Is it "possible" / "easy" to update this widget in order to display the project name / description in place of project id ?

By the way, I was adding this widget on a project dashboard, not on the main page.

Anyway, this is not a big deal, just wanted to notice it.

Etienne

Comment: I am seeing the same thing and it's kind of "bad" to see only guid. Coudln't they just map it to the project name? :)

Answer (score 0):

The key is not the project id by the issue key, which format is an UUID.
It's not possible to display another think, because without the UUID, the uniquness